# How to implement infinite loop by RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I need to listen to a socket as long as the app is alive. We do it in this way in Java (infinite loop):

```
public void listen() throws Exception {
        String msg;

        while (isRunning) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[5 * 1024]; // Size: 5K
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

            // blocks until a packet is received
            udpSocket.receive(packet);
            msg = bytesToHexString(buf);

            print("Message from " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ": " + msg);
            pm.setNotification(msg);
        }

    }
```

I am able to run it in another thread by using RxJava2 (to prevent Network On Main Thread Exception in Android).

```
try {
            udpClient = new UDPClientMulticast("232.17.29.10", 4444);
            Disposable d1 = Single.just(udpClient)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .map(client -> {
                        client.listen();
                        return true;
                    })
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(isListening -> print("UDP Client is listening: " + isListening), t -> print("Error: " + t.getMessage()));
            cd.add(d1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Even though it is working, I think this is super ugly. Is there any `Rx` way that let me to simulate infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Why use RxJava for this?  There's no need to.  Just start a thread.  You're overcomplicating things by adding in Rx at all.

Comment: Ya, that's what I felt. So, just for sake of curiosity I am asking.

Comment: Why not leaving a comment? You do know it isn't a valid answer :) The question is interesting per se .

Comment: @Onik Because sometimes the answer is don't.  Like it is here.  RxJava is a completely abused library that isn't really well suited for most of the things its used for, and this would be one of them.